# Get package version for conda meta.yaml from source file

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to reorganize my python package versioning so I only have to update the version in one place, preferably a python module or a text file. For all the places I need my version there seems to be a way to load it from the source `from mypkg import __version__` or at least parse it out of the file as text. I can't seem to find a way to do it with my conda meta.yaml file though. Is there a way to load the version from an external source in the meta.yaml file?

I know there are the git environment variables, but I don't want to tag every alpha/beta/rc commit that gets tested through out local conda repository. I could load the python object using `!!python/object` in pyyaml, but conda doesn't support arbitrary python execution. I don't see a way to do it with any other jinja2 features. I could also write a script to update the version number in more than one place, but I was really hoping to only modify one file as the definitive version number. Thanks for any help.

Comment: FYI for anyone coming to this before it gets a better answer: I have settled on git tags *and* I added a special command to my setup.py for bumping the version in some of the packaging tools I'm using (Inno Setup for Windows), my `version.py`, and doing the git commits and tags needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to get to your endpoint.  Here's what conda itself does...

The source of truth for conda's version information is `__version__` in `conda/__init__.py`.  It can be loaded programmatically within python code as `from conda import __version__` as you suggest.  It's also hard-wired into `setup.py` [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/5a8e020/setup.py#L56) (note [this code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/5a8e020/setup.py#L25-L31) too), so from the command line `python setup.py --version` is the canonical way to get that information.

In 1.x versions of conda-build, putting a line

```
$PYTHON setup.py --version > __conda_version__.txt
```

in `build.sh` would set the version for the built package using our source of truth.  **The `__conda_version__.txt` file is deprecated**, however, and it will likely be removed with the release of conda-build 2.0.  In recent versions of conda-build, the preferred way to do this is to use `load_setup_py_data()` within a jinja2 context, which will give you access to all the metadata from `setup.py`.  Specifically, in the `meta.yaml` file, we'd have something like this

```
package:
  name: conda
  version: "{{ load_setup_py_data().version }}"
```

---

Now, how the `__version__` variable is set in `conda/__init__.py`...

What you [see in the source code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/5a8e020/conda/__init__.py#L23) is a call to the [`auxlib.packaging.get_version()`](https://github.com/kalefranz/auxlib/blob/8523d3f/auxlib/packaging.py#L144) function.  This function does the following in order

1. look first for a file `conda/.version`, and if found return the contents as the version identifier
2. look next for a `VERSION` environment variable, and if set return the value as the version identifier
3. look last at the `git describe --tags` output, and return a version identifier if possible (must have git installed, must be a git repo, etc etc)
4. if none of the above yield a version identifier, return `None`

Now there's just one more final trick.  In conda's [`setup.py` file](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/8523d3f/setup.py#L78-L81), we set `cmdclass` for `build_py` and `sdist` to those provided by `auxlib.packaging`.  Basically we have

```
from auxlib import packaging
setup(
    cmdclass={
        'build_py': packaging.BuildPyCommand,
        'sdist': packaging.SDistCommand,
    }
)
```

These special command classes actually modify the `conda/__init__.py` file in built/installed packages so the `__version__` variable is hard-coded to a string literal, and doesn't use the `auxlib.packaging.get_version()` function.

---

In your case, with not wanting to tag every release, you could use all of the above, and from the command line set the version using a `VERSION` environment variable.  Something like

```
VERSION=1.0.0alpha1 conda build conda.recipe
```

In your `build` section meta.yaml recipe, you'll need add a `script_env` key to tell conda-build to pass the `VERSION` environment variable all the way through to the build environment.

```
build:
  script_env:
    - VERSION
```

Comment: I would add that there are examples of this in https://github.com/conda/conda-build/tree/master/tests/test-recipes/metadata/source_setup_py_data and that this works with any way of setting the version in setup.py - versioneer, setuptools-scm, or whatever.  Also note that load_setup_py_data used to be named load_setuptools. This changed in 1.21.12.  Both names are valid right now, but load_setuptools will output a warning message about being deprecated.

Comment: Awesome. Judging by the PR for `load_setup_py_data` it looks like this hasn't been available (at least as it is named now) for very long. Thanks for the help, I'll try it out today. ...but while I have your attention, should bug reports (seg faults, etc) for packages from anaconda go in `conda/conda` or `ContinuumIO/anaconda-recipes`?

Comment: bug reports for packages should usually go to ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues .  If you have specific improvements to a recipe, please file a PR or issue on ContinuumIO/anaconda-recipes.

conda/conda is specifically for issues with conda, the package management tool.

Comment: @msarahan That is what I thought but it seems there are so many issues on conda/conda for packages I wasn't sure.

Comment: @kalefranz Thanks for letting me know about `load_setup_py_data`, this is exactly what I needed. Any plans to have this documented?

Comment: Is the value of $VERSION supposed to overwrite the value in __init__.py in the git repository? In my trials, the latter is kept (`WRITING build/lib/PACKAGENAME/.version with version 0.1`) even though the environment variable is acknowledged (`UserWarning: The environment variable 'VERSION' is being passed through with value 9.0.`).

Comment: @kalefranz How should the build and run depedency on auxlib be managed? In particular, what should I write in my meta.yml and setup.py?

Answer (score 15):

As of `conda-build-3.16.1` (Nov-2018) here is what works to programmatically setup `version` inside the conda recipe.

The examples are a part of `meta.yaml` that you pass to `conda-build`, as explained [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html).

#### A. Tap into `setup.py`'s version:

This recipe is perfect if you build a python package, since `setup.py` needs it anyway, so you must have figured that one out already.

```
{% set data = load_setup_py_data() %}

package:
  name: mypackage
  version: {{ data.get('version') }}
```

note that sometimes you have to tell the conda recipe explicitly where to find it, if it's not in the same dir as `setup.py`:

```
{% set data = load_setup_py_data(setup_file='../setup.py', from_recipe_dir=True) %}
```

and now proceed with:

```
$ conda-build conda-recipe
```

---

#### B. Git env variables

This recipe is good if your project is tagged in git, and you use a tag format that conda accepts as a valid version number (e.g. `2.5.1` or `v2.5.1`).

```
package:
  name: hub
  version: {{ GIT_DESCRIBE_TAG }}
```

and now proceed with:

```
$ conda-build conda-recipe
```

---

#### C. Pass env variable:

This one is useful for non-python conda packages, where the version comes from a variety of different places, and you can perfect its value - e.g. convert `v2.5.1` into `2.5.1`.

```
package:
  name: mypkg
  version: {{ environ.get('MYPKG_VERSION', '') }}
```

Then create an executable script that fetches the version, let's call it `script-to-get-mypkg-version`

and now proceed with loading the env var that will set the version:

```
$ MYPKG_VERSION=`script-to-get-mypkg-version` conda-build conda-recipe
```

Depending on the conda-build version, you may have to use `os.environ.get` instead of `environ.get`. The [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/source/resources/define-metadata.html?highlight=environ.get#templating-with-jinja) use the latter.

---

#### This doesn't work

Note that if this used to work in the past, as described in one of the answers from 2016, it doesn't work now.

```
package:
  name: mypkg
build:
  script_env:
    - VERSION

$ VERSION=`script-to-get-mypkg-version` conda-build conda-recipe
```

`conda-build` ignores env var `VERSION` in this case.

[source](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html?highlight=version#templating-with-jinja).

Comment: For C, I think it should be `os.environ.get`. `environ.get` didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks, added this possibility. The [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/source/resources/define-metadata.html?highlight=environ.get#templating-with-jinja) use it without `os`, and it worked for me without it, perhaps they stopped importing `from os` recently.

Answer (score 1):

## Manual `__version__`

If you have the version in a separate `_version.py` that you can import without loading the whole package.

```
# coding: utf-8
# file generated by setuptools_scm
# don't change, don't track in version control
version = '0.0.9.post2+g6481728.d20200518.dirty'
```

In my case this gets automatically generated, but the next step stays the same.

in `__init__.py` you have a line `from ._version import version as __version__`

and then in `setup.py` you could do something like this. 
This is also how I import the version in my sphinx `conf.py`

```
source_dir = Path("src/<my_package>")
sys.path.insert(0, str(source_dir))

from _version import  version

setup(version=version)
...
```

Alternatively, instead of importing the `_version` file, you can try to parse it manually, so you don't have to add something to `sys.path`

and then in `meta.yaml`

```
{% set data = load_setup_py_data() %}
{% set version = data.get('version')  %}


package:
  name: <my_package>
  version: {{ version }}
```

---

I had the reverse issue. I forgot to update my version from time to sime, so was looking for a way to have the `git` repository as single source of the package version. I used [`setuptools_scm`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/)

I've tried a lot of things, with and without pep517 compliant `pyproject.toml` etcetera, but eventually, this is the one that works for me.

The advantage of this is you don't need that huge `versioneer.py`, but it gets written to `_version.py` at build time

## `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup
import setuptools_scm


def my_local_scheme(version: setuptools_scm.version.ScmVersion) -> str:
    """My local node and date version."""
    node_and_date = setuptools_scm.version.get_local_node_and_date(version)
    dirty = ".dirty" if version.dirty else ""
    return str(node_and_date) + dirty

version = setuptools_scm.get_version(
    write_to="src/<my_package>/_version.py",
    version_scheme="post-release",
    local_scheme=my_local_scheme,
)
setup(version=version,)
```

The rest of the `setup()` metadata and options in in `setup.cfg`. One that needs to be there is:

```
[options]
package_dir=
    =src
packages = <my_package>
install_requires = setuptools_scm
```

### `src/<my_package>/_version.py`

gets generated:

```
# coding: utf-8
# file generated by setuptools_scm
# don't change, don't track in version control
version = '0.0.3.post0+g887e418.d20200518.dirty'
```

and I add it to my `.gitignore`

### `src/<my_package>/__init__.py`

```
"""<package_description>"""
from ._version import version as  __version__
```

### `meta.yaml`

```
{% set data = load_setup_py_data() %}
{% set version = data.get('version')  %}


package:
  name: capacity_simulation
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  path: .

build:
  noarch: python
  number: {{ environ.get('GIT_DESCRIBE_NUMBER', 0) }}
  script: python -m pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed .
  include_recipe: False

requirements:
  build:
    - setuptools_scm
...
```

## `pyproject.toml`

To also be able to use `pip wheel .`

you need this section in `pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=34.4", "wheel", "setuptools_scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Comment: So for the answer to my original question, you are repeating what @stason has in their answer (part A), right?

Comment: yes, but the source where the `setup.py` gets the version is automated from the CVS. I have been looking around for this quite a bit, so I thought to share my solution. If you set it manually in your `__init__.py`. you can load this in your `setup.py`

Comment: It seems like i misread your question a bit. I added how to get it from another file. I use that in my sphinx `conf.py`