# conda build: how to embed version number in python project

Tags: conda, miniconda, conda-build

i'd like to be able to do:

```
import pyproject
print(pyproject.__version__)
```

in a conda built Python project `pyproject`

I can't figure out how to do this in the meta.yaml, or find an example on conda-forge where this is done.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get package version for conda meta.yaml from source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919840/get-package-version-for-conda-meta-yaml-from-source-file)

Comment: Also https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/zOLMF4CfnAU which has much clearer answers